# how to know where user starting chat? from inside group or from inside bot directly?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I have created telegram bot using telegraf.js

The bot is working correctly, however I need to handle a different thing if the user send message from inside bot directly, let's say the bot should replay with help commands documentations (for example).

the question is:

how to recoginze where the user start chatting? from inside chat group or from inside bot directly?

I tried

```
 var groupInfo =await ctx.telegram.getChat()
```

without success

I thing the solution would be simple, but I can't find it till now.

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout Telegram docs for [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#chat) type. It has a field called `Type` and according to the docs:

> Type of chat, can be either “private”, “group”, “supergroup” or “channel”

So in telegraf.js you can check the field this ways:

```js
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
    return ctx.reply(`Chat type is: ${ctx.message.chat.type}`)
})
```

In your case, `ctx.message.chat.type == "private"` would be messages that are sent to your bot privately and `ctx.message.chat.type == "group"` or `ctx.message.chat.type == "supergroup"` are messages sent to groups.